# Bio.Motifs throws KeyError 'd'

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm using Biopython to process some NGS data.
But I meet a strange problem when I use **motif** module in Biopython.
Here is the code.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Spacer': seqs1.values()}, index=seqs.keys())
Motif = motifs.create(frame.Spacer.values, alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACAmbiguousDNA())
```

then I get a Keyerror:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Bio\motifs\__init__.py", line 23, in create
    return Motif(instances=instances, alphabet=alphabet)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Bio\motifs\__init__.py", line 244, in __init__
    counts = self.instances.count()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Bio\motifs\__init__.py", line 199, in count
    counts[letter][position] += 1
KeyError: 'd'
```

the seqs1 has these elements:

```
seqs1 ={'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:18193:49320': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:26250:49320': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:26534:49320': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:27651:49320': 'GGCACNGCGGCTGGAGGNGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:28625:49320': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:4503:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGNGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:5781:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:6005:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:8176:49338': 'GGCGCTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:11099:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:15564:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:17553:49338': 'GGCGCTTCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:22059:49338': 'GGCGCTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:24129:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:24535:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:30117:49338': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:22191:49355': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:25134:49355': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:7243:49373': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:10064:49373': 'GGCGCTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG', 'E00491:315:HVLGTCCXY:1:1101:14752:49373': 'GGCACTGCGGCTGGAGGTGG'}
```

there is no 'd' in my sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was also asked on Biopython's GitHub page and was solved there (https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1978)

In short: `Bio.motifs.create()` expects a list of sequences as input (e.g. `['ATTG', 'CTTG', ...]`). The Pandas DataFrame operation shown above does not do what the author of the question intends to do.

He can just do:

```
Motif = motifs.create(seqs1.values(), alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACAmbiguousDNA())
```

Comment: Sorry I'm layman in programmer's netiquette . Should I remove this question?   
(。﹏。*)

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct (because it solves your problem). So people who come here with a similar question will find an answer.